# adding line breaks between javascript array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wonder if someone can help with this task; I found this great code for a daily quote and I am just trying to put a line break between the daily quote and the author of the quote. I thought maybe creating a two dimensional array would make it easier, but unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to put the line break. Thank you. Here is the code so far:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 

var quote = new Array()
for (i=0; i<7; i++){
quote[i] = new Array(6)
}

quote[0][0] = 'If you want to go fast go alone, if you want to go far go together!'; 
quote[0][1] = 'African Proverb';
quote[1][0] = 'We either make ourselves happy or miserable. The amount of work is the same.'; 
quote[1][1] = 'Carlos Castaneda'; 
quote[2][0] = 'Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not any simpler.'; 
quote[2][1] = 'Albert Einstein';
quote[3][0] = 'Failure is the mother of success.'; 
quote[3][1] = 'Chinese Proverb'; 
quote[4][0] = 'The first to apologize is the bravest. The first to forgive is the strongest. The first to forget is the happiest.' 
quote[4][1] = 'Unknown';
quote[5][0] = 'If an egg is broken by an outside force, life ends. If it is broken by an inside force life begins. Great things happen from the inside.'; 
quote[5][1] = 'Unknown';
quote[6][0] = 'Simplicity is the ultimate sophistication.' 
quote[6][1] = 'Leonardo Da Vinci';

var qlen = quote.length;
var firstDate = new Date(2016,2,25);//start date (yyyy,m,d) - m=0=January, m=1=February
var today = new Date();//today
var dif = Math.floor((today-firstDate)/1000/60/60/24);//difference in days
while(dif>=qlen){//calculate the index of the quote of the day 
dif=dif-qlen;//restart the array index if the difference is greater that the    array's length 
} 
var todayQuote = quote[dif][0];//the quote of the day 
var todayQuoteOwner = quote[dif][1];//author of the quote of the day

onload = function(){document.getElementById('q').firstChild.data = todayQuote + </n>  + document.getElementById('qu').firstChild.data = todayQuoteOwner}


</script> 

<div>  id='q'; </div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('q').firstChild.data = todayQuote + "\r\n"  + document.getElementById('qu').firstChild.data = todayQuoteOwner`?

Comment: or if outputting to html, `document.getElementById('q').firstChild.data = todayQuote + "<br/>" + document.getElementById('qu').firstChild.data = todayQuoteOwner`?

Comment: There's an </n> that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Fix the HTML code first. It should be like `<div id="q"><p></p></div>`. Secondly, where you want to put line break exactly. Why you don't create html and add div innerHTML?

Comment: @guest420420 - I can't seem to get that to work - yes this is inside html   code - I didn't write that part as i thought that was irrelevant;

Comment: @N Moeini - OK I fixed the html; What I'm trying to do is have the author's name written in a separate line (following line) rather the same line. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I recommend is moving the `<script></script>` content to the end rather than the beginning, so that way there's no need for an onload function.

Your javascript also refers to a `qu` element but your `html` code didn't include it. For the time being I'm going to assume it's just another `div` but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Your javascript also seems to set the quote and author to a `firstChild.data` but your `html` doesn't have any children in the `div`. So if you actually were to run this, there will be a null error therefore I've added a nested `<p />` to each. And for the sake of testing, I've included `innerHTML` as well so you can see the results.

```
<div id="q"><p></p></div>
<div id="qu"><p></p></div>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    // ... generate the quotes and authors ...
    var qElement = document.getElementById('q');
    var quElement = document.getElementById('qu');

    qElement.firstChild.innerHTML = qElement.firstChild.data = todayQuote;
    quElement.firstChild.innerHTML = quElement.firstChild.data = todayQuoteOwner;
</script>
```

If you're looking to just have one element container for both the quote and author, then just get rid of the `qu` element altogether and separate the two parts by a `< br/>` element.

```
<div id="q"><p></p></div>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
    // ... generate the quotes and authors ...
    var qElement = document.getElementById('q');

    qElement.firstChild.innerHTML = qElement.firstChild.data = todayQuote + '<br/>' + todayQuoteOwner;
</script>
```

Comment: thank you so much, worked like a charm. Informative and well explained.